# Book about a girl who finds her magic through the help of time travelling witches

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I’m trying to find a book I read between 2013-2015.

The book was about a girl (all family dead I’m 90% sure from a car crash and she was the only survivor - she was also a twin) who meets a family of witches. She doesn’t know they’re witches at first etc. She finds out they’re witches and they time travelled from the early 1900s to help her gain her magic to fulfil some prophecy. She falls in love with the son and becomes best friends with the daughter. Also I think someone’s trying to kill them all but not completely certain.

I’m pretty sure she helped the family paint their house when they first moved in and she often visited her family in a cemetery.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details? For example, how long ago was when you were younger?

Answer (score 4):

## [Swift](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15990930-swift?from_search=true) (2012) by Heather London

> A girl totally unaware of her destiny.
>
> Two men who will stop at nothing to take her power.
>
> One family who will do whatever it takes to protect her.
>
> After graduating from high school, Meredith is ready to leave the place that has been a constant reminder of what happened to her as a child. She was just eight years old when her family died in a mysterious car accident, taking the secret of her destiny with them. It’s not until a new family moves to town that she realizes leaving may not be as easy as she once thought.
>
> Meredith feels an instant connection towards the Harpers, especially the good-looking, mysterious Blake and his overly friendly sister, Abby. After a series of bizarre events that happen too often to be coincidence, Meredith begins to realize that she is at the center of something larger than herself—possibly the same thing that killed her parents and twin sister many years ago. Nightmarish visions and resurfacing memories push Meredith closer to Blake, leading her to discover her destiny and other buried secrets.
>
> As Meredith tries to understand her new world, she will be put to the ultimate test, and her strength and courage will be challenged more than she ever imagined.

Comment: I've added information to the book I believe you think it is, if I'm wrong you can [edit] this to remove what I just did. You will also be able to accept this self answer in approximately two days, please come back and do so!